# Does anyone know how to configure dates from SAS to SPSS?

Tags: sas, spss

I'm having trouble transforming dates from SAS to SPSS. I used the following coding but my dates, that should be all in 2020, is showing up as 2080. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong with my code? I'd appreciate having your input. Thank you very much.

```
COMPUTE spss_date1=(VAR_fromSAS +xdate.tday(date.mdy(1,1,1960)))*86400.
Formats spss_date1 (adate10).
list VAR_fromSAS spss_date1.
EXECUTE.
```

Example of my Output:

44063  |   08/21/2080
44070  |   08/28/2080
44092  |   09/19/2080

Comment: Do you know the original meaning of the date values in your example? If so, please edit your post and add them - might help us understand what the problem is. In any case, knowing nothing about dates in SAS, is it possible you meant 1900 and not 1960 in the code?

Comment: Hi Eli, thank you very much for replying. I don't know the exactely dates in SAS but I know that the data was collect in 2020 and 2021, and this variable is the date that the date was collected. I checked my code and I used 1960. Thank you, Erica

Comment: The first numbers (44063, 44070, 44092) are my dates in SAS

Comment: When importing dates from Excel, for example, the dates are calculated relative to `1.1.1900` ([eg. see here](https://www.spsstools.net/en/syntax/syntax-index/dates-and-time/importing-from-excel-convert-days-into-dates/)). I don't know where you got the code you posted, but I suspect the error may be in using 1960 instead of 1900. Seems reasonable because once you correct to 1900 the result should go to 2020 instead of 2080.

Comment: It is true. The data was sent to me in excel. I changed to 1.1.1900 and it worked. Thank you very much.